# Image file types indexed by Google: is TIFF part of it or not?

Tags: seo, tiff, google-search, google-search-console

The image file types indexed by Google are defined:

1. On the [Google Webmaster / Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2598805?hl=en) where the TIFF format is not present (latest update 2015):

Google can index the following image types:

```
BMP
GIF
JPEG
PNG
WebP
SVG
```

2. But on the [Google Search Appliance Documentation](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/file_formats/file_formats.html#1081645) the TIFF format is present (latest update 2013):

TIFF Group 5 & 6 - tiff - Versions through 6

TIFF CCITT Group 3 & 4 -tiff - Versions through 6

Can someone confirm that TIFF is part or not part of the supported image file types that Google can index or not? Or give me a hint how I could verify this in a simple, fast and efficient way?

For now my reference is the first link with the Search Console Help (which was updated in 2015), but the second link (from 2013) has given me doubts... Or am I mixing two different things?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The person that down voted this question should have let a message to explain why. I have researched this question on Google and have found two responses on official google documents, which are contradictory. I am asking SEO experts to clarify. It is unfair to down vote without giving a valid reason. If you down vote, this means you have found the question through a research and something has awoken your interest and now you are deceived because you did not got the answer you wanted. But there is no reason to down vote because you are frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarifying directly on Google Search Console, the latest document from 2015 is the one that is right. So this question is closed for me.